# I'm trying to get message from telegram channel but when I run this code I get strange output

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I don't know what to do, for me it seems like no problem is here but it is. I can get last message ID with bot on telegram I can insert URL but that output is strange, infinite loop.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)
# Setting configuration values
api_id = 'my_api_is'
api_hash ='my_api_hash'

phone = 'my_phone_number'
username = 'my_username'

# Create the client and connect
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("Client Created")
# Ensure you're authorized
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    try:
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))

user_input_channel = input("enter entity(telegram URL or entity id):")

if user_input_channel.isdigit():
    entity = PeerChannel(int(user_input_channel))
else:
    entity = user_input_channel

my_channel = client.get_entity(entity)

actual_id = 'Id of last message' 
last_mess = ''
while True:
    actual_mess = client.get_messages(
        entity=my_channel,
        limit=1,
        ids=actual_id
    )
    if actual_mess != last_mess:
        actual_id = actual_id + 1
        last_mess = actual_mess
        print(last_mess)
```

It's like this:

```
<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F90C8>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F9148>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F90C8>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F9148>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F90C8>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F9148>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F90C8>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F9148>

<coroutine object MessageMethods.get_messages at 0x000002313D2F90C8>
```

I will appreciate every help guys!!! I'm starting programmer with good ideas for programs to invent.

Comment: I don't think that the right way to get what you need,  whatever it is. By the way you're getting an "infinite loop" just because you're using the `while` operator. And at least you're printing a `python coroutine` not the actual message object.

Comment: You're printing the object itself, use `dir` to see which functions or members can help you to convert it to string, ir look in docs.

Comment: Either use the `telethon.sync` module or use the proper python `async/await` syntax. also you're calling `client.get_messages` without any changes in param (no offset.. ), And I've no clue what you're trying to achieve with the `if` clause

Comment: I wanted to do it like this, it will read last message of channel and when there will be new message it will use that message as input for something else, I just don't know how to get that last message. I need only text from messages. Can you create something what will work like this what I whote?